# Display Emoji from unicode in UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, unicode, emoji

I am working on emoji in chat app.

When someone send me emoji in message it look like this type :- `Hello...(worried) how are you(happy)?`. Here `(worried)and (happy)` are assigned keys for emojis.

This is list for emojis and key and value.

```
dictemoji = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"worried-48.gif",@"(worried)",
                                 @"sad-48.gif",@"(sad)",
                                 @"bandit48.gif",@"(bandit)",
                                 @"wink48.gif",@"(wink)",
                                 @"surprised48.gif",@"(surprised)",
                                 @"smirking48.gif",@"(smirking)",
                                 @"laugh48.gif",@"(laugh)",
                                 @"cool48.gif",@"(cool)",
                                 @"stoned-48.gif",@"(stoned)",
                                 @"smile-48.gif",@"(smile)",
                                 @"nerd-48.gif",@"(nerd)",
                                 @"happy-48.gif",@"(happy)",
                                 @"evil-grin-48.gif",@"(evil-grin)",
                                 @"tongue48.gif",@"(tongue)",
                                 @"lips-sealed-48.gif",@"(lips-sealed)",
                                 @"GIF48.gif",@"(GIF)",
                                 @"dull48.gif",@"(dull)",
                                 nil];
```

When I received message `Hello...(worried) how are you(happy)?` I want to saw my emoji instead of *(worried)and(happy)* in label.

**So how can I take emoji instead of those words?**

**EDIT:-**
When someone send me emoji with text message, it will replace with dictionary value :

```
    for (NSString *emojiKey in dictemoji.allKeys)
    {
        if ([message containsString:emojiKey])
        {
            message = [message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:emojiKey withString:[dictemoji valueForKey:emojiKey]];
        }
    }
    // helllo(sad)...how are you(smile)...? ----->it will look like helllo(sad-48.gif)...how are you(smile-48.gif)...?

    NSLog(@"message updated:%@",message);
    cell.textLabel.text=message;
```

So, I want to display emoji where **(sad-48.gif)** and **(smile-48.gif)** printed in label.

Comment: @ChintaN thanks..I have already check this link but this is not which i am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help you.

Add one label & write the following code in `viewDidLoad` :

```
NSData *dataa = [valueUnicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *valueEmoj = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataa encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

_lbl.text = valueEmoj;
```

Comment: I have enter valueUnicode=@"(cool)" as it is in my dictionary but it show me (cool) in label.

Comment: u must be unicode for displaying emoji...see this link http://punchdrunker.github.io/iOSEmoji/table_html/ all  emoji have specific unicode

Comment: I have my personal emoji so when i want to convert it into unicode        NSString *unicode=@"nerd-48.gif";
    NSData *dataa = [unicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *valueEmoj = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataa encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

it give me output like as it is in string nerd-48.gif

Comment: you can't use any  dictionary in your code..plz give me your code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this ;

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dictemoji valueForKey:emojiKey]];

NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My label text"];
[myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

cell.attributedText = myString;
```

hope this will help.